# how to call a .aspx file in a .ascx file with json/ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I'm currently trying to build a pretty large website, using ASP.net, combined with vb.net or C#. Currently I'm working on a bit, where the user presses on a button and a bit of special text appears (described like that to make this explenation relatively simple). I'd like to use ajax/json to call a .aspx file, to show in a little block on the site. The .aspx file would have a method of it's own that generates the output, so all I need is for the .ascx file to call the aspx file, maybe specify that method and pass a parameter.

I'll post my code below, could anyone take a look please? Please tell me if I forgot something important or something's not clear. I'm not a pro in this though

PollDetail.ascx

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/excanvas/r3/excanvas.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chart.js/0.2/Chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div runat="server" id="form1">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            LoadChart();
            $("[id*=ddlCountries]").bind("change", function () {
                LoadChart();
            });
        });
        function LoadChart() {
            var chartType = parseInt($("[id*=rblChartType] input:checked").val());
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "PollGrafiek.aspx/GetChart", //PollDetail.ascx/GetChart
                data: "{pollID: '" + $("getPollID") + "'}", //+ $("[id*=ddlCountries]").val() +
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    $("#dvChart").html("");
                    $("#dvLegend").html("");
                    var data = eval(r.d);
                    var el = document.createElement('canvas');
                    $("#dvChart")[0].appendChild(el);

                    //Fix for IE 8
                    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == "8.0") {
                        G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(el);
                    }
                    var ctx = el.getContext('2d');
                    var userStrengthsChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var div = $("<div />");
                        div.css("margin-bottom", "10px");
                        div.html("<span style = 'display:inline-block;height:10px;width:10px;background-color:" + data[i].color + "'></span> " + data[i].text);
                        $("#dvLegend").append(div);
                    }
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert('There was an error.');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

PollGrafiek.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PollGrafiek.aspx.cs" Inherits="PollGrafiek" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/excanvas/r3/excanvas.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chart.js/0.2/Chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div runat="server" id="form1">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Country:
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountries" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="USA" Value="USA" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Brazil" Value="Brazil" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="dvChart">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="dvLegend">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PollGrafiek.aspx.cs

```
public partial class PollGrafiek : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetChart(int pollID)
    {
        return the output for the 
    }
}
```

Comment: what error do you get and your url should be url: "PollGrafiek.aspx/GetChart",

Comment: no error yet, just doesn't show anything yet. and right, good call, missed that one

Comment: Please check your network tab to see if the request is sent and also check its header

Comment: I checked the network tab and clicked on the button (after which the info should be shown), but I didn't see anything of the .aspx file. I'm fairly sure it doesn't get called correctly.

Comment: Where did you added "PollDetail.ascx" in PollGrafiek.aspx page?

Comment: in the ajax function, nowhere else. Do I need to call it somewhere else as well? MMaybe in a panel that only shows after the button is clicked?

Comment: If you want to use UserControl you need to add it in aspx page

Comment: the info is currently stocked in .aspx page, that's no problem. I have trouble calling that .aspx page from my .ascx page though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you url should be

`PollGrafiek.aspx/GetChart`

hope this helps...

Comment: Yeah, already changed that, but it still doesn't work. No error, but nothing shows either. I suspect the ajax functions aren't quite complete yet

Comment: @I_Am_Not_user3185054 did you put break point in your method and make sure that it return the value

Comment: right, I tend to forget that. I just tried it, but the system doesn't go into the 'getChart' method.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the data as a string

```
data: "{pollID: '" + $("getPollID") + "'}"
```

But you most likely want

```
data: { pollID: $("getPollID") }
```

Comment: mmhm, that's possible yeah. PollId itself is an int parameter that the method needs in the .aspx file, though it doesn't have access to it over there, which is why it's a paramter. GetPollID is a method in .ascx to  give that parameter. I'll try that.